# How to let WebViewClient load websites that are not google.com in own activity

Tags: android, webview, webviewclient

How must my WebViewClient be so all Websites that are not Google.com are loaded in an external WebView within it's own activity?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont know what you exactly want. You can define a webview in your layout and load a url in there.

```
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_webview, container, false);

    WebView webView = (WebView) v.findViewById(R.id.webView);
    webView.setWebViewClient(new DefaultWebClient());

    webView.loadUrl("http://www.your.domain");
    webView.requestFocus(View.FOCUS_DOWN);
```

If you want to make sure that only pages which are not starting with google are loaded into your webview, you may set a new WebViewClient() and override it like here:

```
  wv.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient()   {
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url)        {               
                return false;                            
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url)
    {
        super.onPageFinished(view, url);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon)
    {
        super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
        String url_new = view.getUrl();             
        if (url_new.toLowerCase().contains("google.com")) { .... do your stuff ... } 
    }
});
```